# EWS for Web based add-ins for Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to develop an Outlook Web Add-In but have a few queries related to EWS:

That [documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-requirements) that EWS must be enabled and must be exposed to the internet for on-premises installations of Exchange Server.

Questions:

1. Do all Office Web Add-Ins require EWS to be enabled on the server?
2. Is it mandatory for EWS to be exposed to the internet for Add-Ins to work?

Our customer has an on-premises installation of Exchange Server and has EWS enabled, but does not want to expose it to the internet for security reasons.

The Add-In we are trying to develop is for internal employees only and will not be accessed from outside the company network zone.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a hard requirement so long as your add-in doesn't make any calls that *require* EWS. That said, it is **strongly** recommended.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your answer. Just to clarify do you mean:

1. If the Add-In just makes use of Office.js and not make any direct EWS calls, there is no need for EWS?

2. If the answer to 1 above is No, assuming Office.js internally makes use of EWS for some of the functionality, is it mandatory for EWS to be exposed to the internet?

Thanks for your help here.

Comment: There are Office.js APIs such as makeEwsRequestAsync and getUserIdentityTokenAsync that rely on EWS. If these APIs are leveraged in the add-in and the Exchange Server is not exposed to the internet this would impact the ability of users to utilize the add-in when connected to Exchange over the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Just a few more clarifications and we will be good to go:

Considering the following scenario:
1. Exchange users connect to the Exchange Server only over the intranet. 
2. EWS is not exposed to the internet


Q: Can the AddIn function properly if it does not call any of the Office.js API's that rely on EWS?
Q: Can the AddIn function properly even if it calls Office.js APIs that rely on EWS?

It is difficult to setup a test environment to do a POC in order to test our development requirements and therefore we are seeking some expert advice. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, the add-in should be able to function when calling Office.js APIs that do not rely on EWS when connected to the intranet. For Office.js APIs that do rely on EWS as long as Outlook can access EWS through the intranet the APIs should work as well. Please note that it is still strongly recommended the Exchange server has EWS exposed to the internet. Without exposure to the internet an add-in cannot make EWS calls from the backend and the add-in can only be used when connected to the intranet.